# Mongoose findOne returns null but the document is inserted in the collection while testing using MongoMemoryServer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I am testing an Express REST API with Jest and Supertest and I'm using MongoMemoryServer to avoid modifying my MongoDB production database. Also, I use mongoose to manage the connection to the DB, insert documents, etc. In this case, I am testing an endpoint which allows registering a User into my system.

This is my configuration file where there are three methods: connect and disconnect, which allows me to start and stop the connections, and setupUsuarios, which creates some initial data for the tests.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Usuario = require('../models/Usuario');
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require('mongodb-memory-server');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

let mongod = null;

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        let dbUrl = process.env.CONNECTION_STRING;
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV.trim() === 'test') {
            mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
            dbUrl = mongod.getUri();
        }

        mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });
        console.log(dbUrl);
        console.log('MongoDB connected');

    } 
    
    
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

const disconnectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
        if (mongod) {
            await mongod.stop();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

//Creating some users for the tests that
const setupUsuarios = async () => {

    try {

        const usuario1 = new Usuario({
            nombre: "Usuario Test",
            nombreUsuario: 'userTester',
            email: "test@user.com",
            password: bcrypt.hashSync('12345678', 10)
        })

        await usuario1.save();

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);

    }
}

module.exports = { connectDB, disconnectDB, setupUsuarios };
```

This is my User model (called Usuario), **which works well in production**.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const UsuarioSchema = new Schema({

    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El nombre es obligatorio'],
    },

    nombreUsuario: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, "El nombre de usuario es obligatorio"],
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, "La dirección de correo electrónico es obligatoria"],
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "La contraseña es obligatoria"],
    },

    roles: {
        type:String
    },

    insignias: {
        type: Array
    }},
    {timestamps:true},
    {collection: 'usuarios'});


// elimina la key password del objeto que retorna al momento de crear un usuario
UsuarioSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
    let user = this;
    let userObject = user.toObject();
    delete userObject.password;
    return userObject;
}

UsuarioSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator,  {
    message: "Debe ser único"
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Usuario', UsuarioSchema)
```

And finally, this is my test file. Before the tests are executed, I have a beforeAll method which starts the server, connects to the DB and creates some test data. When the tests have finished, an afterAll method is executed to disconnect from the DB and stop the server.

```js
const supertest = require('supertest');
const { app, server } = require('../index');
const request = supertest(app);
const { connectDB, disconnectDB, setupUsuarios } = require('./mock_database_configuration');
const mongoose =  require('mongoose');
const Usuario = require('../models/Usuario');

describe('TESTS USUARIOS', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        connectDB();
        await setupUsuarios();
    });
    
    afterAll(() => {
        disconnectDB();
        server.close();
    });

    

    describe('TESTS REGISTRO', () => {
        
        describe('CASOS POSITIVOS', () => {
            it('REGISTRO EXITOSO', async () => {
                const response = await request.post('/usuarios/registro').send({
                    nombre: 'Usuario Test',
                    nombreUsuario: 'newUser',
                    email: 'newUser@gmail.com',
                    password: '12345678'
                
                })

                expect(response.status).toBe(200);

                // //check that the user was created: THIS DOES NOT WORK -> USUARIO VARIABLE IS NULL 

                // const usuario = await Usuario.findOne({nombreUsuario: 'newUser'});
                // expect(usuario).not.toBeNull();

                //get collection usuarios with mongoose collection name
                const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();

            // get the collection of users
                const collection = collections.find(collection => collection.collectionName === 'usuarios');

            // get documents of collection -> THE DOCUMENT IS INSERTED CORRECTLY
                const documents = await collection.find().toArray();
                console.log(documents);
                
            })

            })
        })

    })
```

The problem is as follows: When I test the endpoint, everything works, and the User is registered successfully. However, when I try to find the user using my mongoose model and findOne method, it returns null. But when I  find the collection manually, I can see that the user has been inserted correctly.

So, why is findOne() method returning null?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, the problem wasn't Mongoose or my configuration. It was a problem with my register endpoint. I was using an async function to create the User, but I was never using await when saving it, so when the test was executed I was getting null because the user wasn't created yet.

Comment: Please add code or any supporting information of how you solved the problem